# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: DataSource in Glassfish

Tags: java, glassfish, classnotfound

I'm getting a weird problem in GlassFish 2.1 - I'm a beginner with this container and I'm having trouble pinning this down.

I have a new install of GlassFish 2.1 with a JDBC connection pool defined called testDerbyPool. I then have a resource defined called jdbc/testDerbyPool pointing at that pool. The resource type is javax.sql.DataSource and I can successfully ping the pool.

I then have a single class in a webapp with this declaration:

```
@Resource(name="jdbc/testDerbyPool")
private javax.sql.DataSource source;
```

This declaration in my web.xml:

```
  <resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/testDerbyPool</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
  </resource-ref>
```

When I try to deploy the application, I get this error:

```
[#|2009-09-09T21:40:47.582+0100|SEVERE|sun-appserver9.1|javax.enterprise.system.container.web|_ThreadID=24;_ThreadName=Thread-32;_RequestID=1ca4ab80-ae39-4920-be18-f535b025bb51;|WebModule[/cptest1]PWC1275: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener
```

and a huge stack trace, starting:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: LDataSource;
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2291)
```

with root cause:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: DataSource
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1498)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
```

I don't understand how DataSource can be 'not found'! Any ideas?

Comment: Make sure your application doesn't have its own copy of javax.sql.DataSource, it might be clashing with Glassfish's copy.

Comment: That's probably what was happening, cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Next time I went back after asking the question, I noticed a build error in Eclipse, somehow gotten an extra JRE in the path marked 'unbound'. Looking around my system, I got a JVM point release update automatically between starting Eclipse up and doing the build/deploy.

Anyway, removed it, tried again, worked.

So check for build errors and build path problems if you see this problem.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting to look for build errors and warnings. Was getting a NoClassDefFound exception since morning and the reason was logged as warning.